# How to compute confidence interval for variance with unknown mean from a normal $(a,\sigma ^2)$ sample?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

When mean is known, we note that $\frac{\bar{(X-a)^2}n}{\sigma ^2}$ has a Chi-squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom. However, what to do when $a$ is unknown? I can't just substitute sample mean instead of $a$. I haven't found anything on the site or the Internet covering this topic.

Comment: Can you post the whole exercise?

Comment: @callculus from a given sample of 100 observations from a normal distrbution construct the 0.95 level confidence interval for variance presuming the mean unknown. So what i have is 100 numbers and the fact that it's normal.





 I already did for known mean unknown variance, unknown mean known variance, and now when both of them are unknown i did find the interval for the mean through t-distribution, but struggle with the interval for the variance

Comment: Use [the fact](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121662/why-is-the-sampling-distribution-of-variance-a-chi-squared-distribution) that $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2\sim \chi^2_{n-1}$, where $S^2$ is the sample variance.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth This fact is valid for $S^2=\bar{(X-a)^2}$, where $a$ is the true mean. What tells us that it is also valid for $a$ calculated as the sample mean?

Comment: Actually it is valid using the sample mean ($S^2$ is $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \overline{X}_n)^2$, where $n$ is the sample size, $X_i$ is the $i$-th observation, and $\overline{X}_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}X_j$ is the sample mean).

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth So, $\frac{X_1-a}{\sigma}$ is $N(0,1)$ Hence, if we add them up n times, we will have that $\frac{nS^2}{\sigma ^2}$ is Chi-squared with $n$ degrees of freedom, where $S^2=(X_1-a)^2+...+(X_n-a)^2$. In your answer, i've noticed that you use the Bessel's correction. Is this crucial to the fact that you use $\bar{X_n}$ instead of the true mean $a$?

Comment: Yes, this is crucial (well basically the numerator of $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2$ is to be the sum of squared deviations from the sample mean). And when you use $\overline{X}_n$ instead of $a$, then $\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\overline{X}_n)^2}{\sigma^2}$ will be $\chi^2_{n-1}$ instead of $\chi^2_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some confusion here:

- The notation in the first line of your question is garbled. Either you need to have $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - a)^2,$ if you have $n$ observations, or you need $n=1$ if $X$ is your only observation. I suppose this is why @callculus asked you to post the entire question.
- Also, the (first) comment of @minusonetwelfth overlooks that
  the population mean $\mu$ is not unknown and estimated by $\bar X,$ but $\mu = a$ is given.

When the sample mean $\mu - a$ is known the estimate
of variance $\sigma^2$ is $V = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - a)^2$
and $\frac{nV}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n).$

Thus, by the 'pivot' method, a 95% CI form $\sigma^2$ is of the form
$$\left(\frac{nV}{U}, \frac{nV}{L}\right),$$
where $L$ and $U$ cut probability from the lower and upper tails, respectively, of $\mathsf{Chisq}(n).$

---

*Example:*  Let `x` be a vector of $n=10$ observations taken at random from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100, \sigma=15),$ where we are taking $\mu = 100$ to be known, and using the observations in `x` to give an interval estimate of $\sigma^2 = 225.$ (I'm using R statistical software.)

```
set.seed(516)
x = round(rnorm(10, 100, 15),2)
x
 [1]  84.80  85.72  78.11  95.17 107.85 108.01 122.61 111.15 111.46  79.67
stripchart(x, pch="|")
```

[image]

```
V = sum((x-100)^2)/10
V
[1] 224.3417
qchisq(c(.025,.975), 9)
[1]  2.700389 19.022768
CI = n*V/qchisq(c(.975,.025), 9)
CI
[1] 117.9333 830.7754
```

So a 95% CI for $\sigma^2$ is
$(117.93, 830.78).$ The confidence interval
may seem very long, but there isn't much
information about the variance in only $n= 10$ observations. And the 95% confidence interval *does* cover the value 225. [So our example
falls into the 'lucky' 95% of the time that
the confidence interval covers (contains) $\sigma^2.]$

*Notes:* (1) It is easy to see that 
$Q = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i = \mu)^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n).$
We can write $Q = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{X_i - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2,$ where the $Z_i$ are independently standard normal.
A chi-squared random variable with $\nu = n$ is defined as the sum of squares of $n$ independent standard normal random variables.

(2) It is not so easy to show that 
$W=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar X)^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n-1).$
A formal proof uses (a) an $n$-variate orthogonal transformation for which a one-dimensional marginal is related to $\bar X$ and the remaining $n-1$ dimensions are related to $S^2$ or (b) an argument using moment generating functions.

The simulation in R below takes $B=100\,000$ samples of size $n=5$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100, \sigma=15)$ and computes  $W = (n-1)S^2/\sigma^2$ for each sample. A histogram of the $B$ values of $W$ closely matches the density function of $\mathsf{Chisq}(4)$ [solid red], but *not* the density
of $\mathsf{Chisq}(5)$ [dashes].

```
set.seed(2020)
w = replicate(10^5,  4*var(rnorm(5,100,15))/15^2)
hist(w, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2")
  curve(dchisq(x,4), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
  curve(dchisq(x,5), add=T, col="brown", lwd=2, lty="dashed")
```

[image]